# Scheduling in NS2

Tags: scheduling, ns2

I m doing in my project in scheduling algorithms in NS2. To implement scheduling algorithm, whether i have to write code in TCL or C++?

Comment: What kind of scheduling? timer/mail scheduling or appointment/assignment scheduling?

Answer (score 2):

It depends upon the type of scheduling that you are doing. For example if you are writing queue scheduling algorithm then you should write a C++ code.

Answer (score 0):

In NS2; we can write algorithms in both tcl script and C++. TCL scripting is simple and easy while we work with an existing protocol. While coding in C++ you have to create a new protocol and it is little bit tough. Overall, For better result, you must have to code in C++